# django static files aren't updating while live

Tags: html, css, django, jinja2, gunicorn

So it's been a while since I made my website go live using **django**, so I decided to make some changes in some css and js files.

After modifying them, none of the new changes have been updated to the website yet. I am aware that the files may have been cached, but I have read that there is a technique to force the server to update the files, by adding `?version=x` after the file path.

For example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?version=1">`

The problem is that with **django**, I did not reference the static files exactly like that, instead I had to use some **jinja logic**.

Example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static              mainpage/HomePage.css' %}" />`

I tried adding `?version=1` to the end of the file path for mine, but after I looked at the website on my browser, some css seemed to have gone missing, so I decided to go back to my original link.

Does anyone know how I can apply the solution of adding `?version=1` to my case?
I'm pretty new to css and html, and I would be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for my problem was actually very simple!

I didn't know that I needed to run `python3 manage.py collectstatic`, in order to see changes in static files, while already in production.

So yes, next time you make any changes to static files, and want to see the update on your website, you must run **collectstatic**.

Hope this helps anyone who was as confused as I was!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "empty cache and hard reload"  (right click on refresh button with open dev tools in browser (Google Chrome) )  to confirm the issue is caused by cache. If so, and your changes appears after hard reload,  setup ManifestStaticFilesStorage https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage to deal with this problem. It will add hash of the file to it's name,  so any change in file content will cause name change and browser will download new file.